# Force implementation of an interface to use a function, to enable functionality that's transparent to the user

Tags: design, interfaces

I am the designer of an interface `IModel`, which will be used by the implementer of a the controller (MVC). The interface contains `funcA()`. 
Another programmer needs to implement a specific class for the `IModel`.

I want to direct the implementation of `funcA()` to use another function, `funcB()`. This forces some functionality of the specific model class to be transparent. For example, the interface contains `openFile()`, but the specific class must contain the transparent functionality of encrypting the file.

What is better?

1. Defining two interfaces: I1 for the controller side, and another one, I2, for those who implement the model class, where I2 extends I1.
2. My own implementation of an abstract class like `AbsModel` which implements `Imodel` and contains abstract functions.

Answer (score 1):

Abstractly: You cannot control how anyone implements your Interface.
All you can do is force them to have a method that matches your Interface, so that you can use their class - whatever it does - in place of any other class that implements your Interface.

If you want to ensure the class has a method to decrypt the file - whatever file that might be - then you have to add it to your Interface, but then you run the risk that whilst the function must be there, it doesn't *have* to actually do anything (classic example: the DataSet's Binary Serializer that simply wraps the output from the Text Serializer, *unmodified*, into a Byte array!) or it might do something completely different.

There are many, many encryption schemes - which one is your Implementer supposed to use?

I think you should add methods to the Interface for encrypting/ decrypting your files, but also an additional, concrete Class that implements this capability; using this Dependency Injection method, any Implementer of your Interface can instantiate *your* decrypting Class and pass it to their *own* method.